# Don't submit unless a certain radio button is checked

Tags: jquery, onclick, radio-button, submit

I am trying to make a Jquery simple function and just want to submit a form only when the radio button value is "1". If not don't submit the form and change some things as I am showing in the code below.

At the moment if the value of the radio button is "1" or "0" the form is submitting anyway.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.result').hide();
$('input.prettycheckbox').prettyCheckable({});

$('input.submit').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('input.prettycheckbox').each(function(){
        if ($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).is('input[value="0"]')) {
            $(this).attr("disabled", true);;
            $('.result').show();
            $('.advise').hide();
            $(this).parent().parent().addClass('incorrect');
        } else {
                $('form').submit();
            };
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Never a good idea to attach events to a submit button - instead use the form's submit event

```
$(function() {
  $('.result').hide();
  $('input.prettycheckbox').prettyCheckable({});

  $('form').on('submit', function(e) { // use #formid if you have it
      var ok = false;
      $('input.prettycheckbox').each(function(){
        if ($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).is('input[value="0"]')) {
            ok=true; // or other reason
            $(this).attr("disabled", true);;
            $('.result').show();
            $('.advise').hide();
            $(this).parent().parent().addClass('incorrect');
          } // seems to have been missing  
      });
      if (!ok) { // if not ok to submit, THEN preventDefault
         e.preventDefault();
      } 
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm off to bed so I cannot fix any issues until tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

To simplify; override the form submit event and only prevent if the radio value is not 1.

HTML:

```
<form method="post" target="">
    <input type="radio" name="mandatory" value="0" />Selecting me won't work<br />
    <input type="radio" name="mandatory" value="1" />You must select me<br />
    <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Submit" />
<form>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('form').on('submit', function (e) {
        if( $('input[name=mandatory]:checked').val()!= 1)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
        }            
    });

});
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u3amqms6/4/)

Answer (score 0):

bind form to submit event then manually check each checkbox using

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function() { $('.result').hide();
$('input.prettycheckbox').prettyCheckable({});

$('form.form_class').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var chkbx = $('input.prettycheckbox');
    var ret = new Array(chkbx.length);

    for (var i = 0; i < chkbx.length; i++)
    {
        if ($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).is('input[value="0"]')) 
        {
            $(this).attr("disabled", true);;
            $('.result').show();
            $('.advise').hide();
            $(this).parent().parent().addClass('incorrect');
            return false;
            continue;
        }
    }
    return true
    }); 
}); 
</script>
```