# How to show alert and prevent alert to be shown

Tags: javascript, html

How can I pop an alert message when a radio button is not chosen (Please select Radio) when the select option in the form is pass (W3).
Also, how can I prevent alert to show when the select option is reject (W5) and show textarea

```js
var Privileges = jQuery('#one');
var select = this.value;
Privileges.change(function() {
  if ($(this).val() == 'W5') {
    $('.resources').show();
  } else
    $('.resources').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6"></div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group ">
      <h5><b>Remark :</b></h5>
      {{Form::select('remark', ['W3' => 'Pass', 'W5' => 'Reject'], 'W3', ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'one'])}}
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-6"></div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-line resources" style="display: none; margin-top: 20px !important" id="two">
      <h5><b>Note :</b></h5>
      <textarea id="txtArea" name="notep6" class="form-control" rows="5" cols="3"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-10"></div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" id="submit_tenure" style="cursor:pointer;"> {{ csrf_field() }}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post a fiddle containing your js code as well?

Comment: this might help [dont-submit-unless-a-certain-radio-button-is-checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26079276/dont-submit-unless-a-certain-radio-button-is-checked)

Comment: this is my js,, but i dont know how to make alert when pass (W3) & not alert when reject (W5)                                                                                     
         <script type="text/javascript">
        var Privileges = jQuery('#one');
        var select = this.value;
        Privileges.change(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == 'W5') {
                $('.resources').show();
            }
            else $('.resources').hide();
        });
    </script>

Comment: I made a snippet from your html and js code. Would be great if you can convert the form line to the actual html as well.

Comment: So the question is like you need to show an alert when no radio buttons are selected and prevent it and show a text area  if any of the radio buttons are selected right ?

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV if select reject (W5) textarea show,,  and radio button not alert

Comment: You should do this in your submit click, check the Radio button status in the submit button click and there you can define your condition checks